# New Mac User: Favicons for Firefox/Safari bookmarks?

Tags: mac, firefox, safari, macbook-pro, favicon

OK, I'll start by saying that I just bought a new MacBook so I'm working with the factory settings here.

In both Firefox and Safari I am storing bookmarks to the bookmark toolbar. The favicons never appear there, however. Only the title appears. I have tried clicking on the bookmark to get the favicon to load/refresh, restarting the browser, etc but it never shows up. How do I enable favicon display for the bookmark toolbar?

Before anyone asks, yes I am viewing websites that have favicons. To be clear, I have even added superuser.com to the toolbar and it only shows "Super User" with no icon.

Any help is appreciated. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: What theme are you currently using? (Tools -> Add-ons -> Appearance)

Answer (score 0):

Neither Safari nor Firefox has an option for showing favicons on the bookmark bar. Firefox apparently will have the ability in 4.0, but for now, there is [a modification to get favicons to show](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1969907). I haven't tried this, but it looks like it works. No hope for Safari in this respect.

[image: Favicons in Firefox in OS X]

Comment: Funny, favicons show up for me (FF 3.6 on osX, windows7 and Ubuntu). Some FF themes don't show favicons on the bookmarks. Try another theme.